# How to validate file size and dimention using finfo in PHP

Tags: php

I need one help. I am doing the file upload using `finfo in php`. Here I can validate the file type but I need to validate the max file size and dimension. I am explaining my code below.

> upload.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>File Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload-manager.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2>Upload File</h2>
        <label for="fileSelect">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="photo" id="fileSelect">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
        <p><strong>Note:</strong> Only .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png formats allowed to a max size of 5 MB and dimension should be 750*250 pixels.</p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> upload-manager.php:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
    $mimeType = $finfo->buffer($fileContents);
    $whitelist_type = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif');
    $error = null;
    if (!in_array($mimeType,$whitelist_type)) {
        echo 'This is not valid file type';
    }
}
?>
```

Here I can only validate the file type and need to validate the max file size and given dimension.

Answer (score 1):

**To get size use the following code**

```
$maxsize = 2097152;
if($_FILES['photo']['size'] >= $maxsize){
 echo 'File too large. File must be less than 2 megabytes.';
}
```

**for image height and width use following code**

```
$image_info = getimagesize($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]);
$image_width = $image_info[0];
$image_height = $image_info[1];
```